# How to get a value from Custom Indicator with zmq?

Tags: python, zeromq, algorithmic-trading, mql4, pyzmq

I have an MQL4 Custom Indicators and I make the EA ( an Expert Advisor ) to get data into MetaTrader Terminal 4 ( mt4 ).

But, how can I import my custom indicators EA to client zmq to get the value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Q :** *But, how can I import my custom indicators EA to client zmq to get the value ?*

Your `MQL4`-side `ExpertAdvisor` code or `Script` ( ***not*** the `CustomIndicator` one) has to import a DLL first. Then your EA code becomes capable to either **`zmq_bind()`** and receive a remote python-code `.connect()`-s, or ( reciprocally ) `zmq_connect()` to a remote python-code `.bind()`-exposed ZeroMQ's AccessPoint address ( via any feasible transport-class `{ tcp:// | pgm:// | epgm:// | vmci:// | ... }` ( depends on ZeroMQ API-version implemented in DLL-wrapper ( ['ve been using a v2.11](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D%5Bmql4%5D) one ) and on the selected ZeroMQ Scalable Formal Communications Pattern Archetype(s) )

Having done any form or shape of this above sketched interconnect meta-plane, your code can `zmq_send()` / `zmq_receive()` data in whatever scenario you opt to implement. Just serialise / deserialise data and `zmq_send()` them.

```
extern string ZMQ_transport_protocol = "tcp";
extern string ZMQ_address            = "192.168.0.386";
extern string ZMQ_outbound_port      = "1985";

// Include the libzmq.dll abstration wrapper.
#include <mql4zmq.mqh>
```

---

```
...
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int init()
{
   int major[1],
       minor[1],
       patch[1];

   zmq_version( major, minor, patch );

   Print( "Using ZeroMQ version " + major[0] + "." + minor[0] + "." + patch[0] );
   Print( ping( "Hello World" ) );
   
   Print( "NOTE: to use the precompiled libraries you will need to have the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package installed. To Download: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555" );
   
   context = zmq_init( 1 );
   speaker = zmq_socket( context, ZMQ_PUB );
   
   outbound_connection_string =         ZMQ_transport_protocol
                              + "://" + ZMQ_server_address
                              + ":"   + ZMQ_outbound_port;

   if ( zmq_connect( speaker, outbound_connection_string ) == -1 )
   {
      Print( "Error connecting the speaker to the listener's address:port!" );
      return( -1 );
   }
   return( 0 );
}
```

---

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Script start function -OR- re-use as an Expert Advisor int OnTick(...){...} template
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int start()
{
   ...

// Publish current tick value + any iCustom(...) data

   string current_tick = "tick|" + AccountName() + " " + Symbol() + " " + Bid + " " + Ask + " " + Time[0];

   if ( s_send( speaker, current_tick ) == -1 )
        Print( "Error sending message: " + current_tick );
   else
        Print( "Published message: " + current_tick );

   return(0);
  }
```

---

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| expert deinitialization function                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int deinit()
{
   Comment( "Going to tidy-up..." );

// Protect against memory leaks on shutdown.
   zmq_close( speaker );
   zmq_term(  context );

   return(0);
  }
```

Comment: you mean import  libsodium.dll and libzmq.dll on my EA code ?

Comment: Details on using v2.11 DLL are in the link above, Austen Conrad's DLL details are here ( https://github.com/AustenConrad/mql4zmq )

Comment: Thanks I already done with that case!